# What does ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 indicate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

```
# Process: Get Raster Properties
Max_Aggl = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(EucDist_Aggl, "MAXIMUM", "")
print (Max_Aggl)
print float(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
b = int(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
c = b/2
print c
delta = int(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0))
print delta
a = delta/1000
print a
```

This is a part of the code, and the value of Max_Aggl=44250.27734375 (more than 10 digits)
and I have error :

> 44250.27734375
>   44250.2773438
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\NEO\bbbb.py", line 22,
>   in 
>       b = int(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '44250.27734375'

you help me first time to convert the result to value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094717/convert-a-string-to-integer-with-decimal-in-python

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are returning a string and not a number, and there is no direct conversion from float stored string to int in Python. So you should use :

```
delta = int(float(Max_Aggl.getOutput(0)))
```

Comment: There can be a direct conversion from string to int in Python - try `print int("6")` - what you cannot do is use int on a "float stored as a string" i.e. `print int("44250.27734375")` will give the observed error message